# Changing String Resources in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

I added some strings to string resource file in my C#.net project (using MS Visual C# express 2010). Properties of Resource file are set as follows

Copy to output Directory: Copy Always ,
Build Action: Embedded Resource

When I compile the application under the bin/release it creates the folder Resources and copies the StringLiterals.Designer.cs and StringLiterals.resx.

**My Requirement:** 
I need to edit the string resources from another application pro-grammatically.  Using ResXResourceWriter I was able to change the resource file StringLiterals.resx. Could you please let me know if there is a way to use the changed string resources in my main Exe without Recompiling.

Comment: have you looked at any of the `Related` links on the current page to see if any of the post can help I see a post that talks about `reading from Embedded Resources` I can only assume that the opposite should be possible meaning look at the reading and how to and implement the reverse which would be `writing to`

Comment: Thanks DJ.I searched in Related links. This particular topic I could not find any information. Reading and writing into a resource file is not a problem. The question is regarding linking the changed Resource file in exe without Recompiling..

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can change an embedded resource file without recompiling. You should consider using a configurable XML file or writing to the registry. This is usually how application settings are stored. If you're worried about text being stored in a readable format, you might consider encrypting the text before writing to the file and decrypting when you need the text.

Comment: Thanks Cameron for your hint.As I am storing Field labels in string resource , there are many. So option of using Registry is ruled out. XML could be used. But again the reading and writing into XML need to be taken care where as Resource provides all the basic operations necessary.